# R: gganimate with geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to create an animate graph with `gganimate`. My defaul graph, static is something like:[image]

But instead of 3 grouping variables I have 12 (year 0, year 1, year 2, etc.). Instead of plotting all 12 variables together I would like to animate it. To avoid:
[image]

Those kernel densities plots are made as follows:

```
data_decidious %>% tidyr::gather("YEAR", "NDVI", colsPostNDVI) %>%    
  mutate(YEAR = str_remove(YEAR, 'meanNDVIyear')) %>% mutate(YEAR = str_remove(YEAR, 'meanprefire_NDVI')) %>% mutate(YEAR = as.factor(YEAR)) %>%    
  ggplot(aes(NDVI,fill=YEAR)) + geom_density(alpha=.2) + xlim(0.3, 0.7) + ylim(0,46) +
  xlab("Mean NDVI") + ylab("Kernal density") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Comparative"))
```

I have found that this `geom_density()` only works when I add `mutate(YEAR = as.factor(YEAR))`. That means when I add:

```
transition_time(YEAR) + ease_aes('linear')
```

I get the error:

```
Error: time data must either be integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date, difftime, orhms
In addition: Warning message:
In min(cl[cl != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Any idea to animate my graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `YEAR` to a factor is not necessary. Instead simply map `factor(YEAR)` on `fill`. This way you can use `YEAR` in transition time and everything is fine.

Using the `gapminder::gapminder` dataset as example data the following code plots and animates the density of worldwide life-expectancy over time.

(BTW: Instead of using a categorical color scale you can map `YEAR` directly on `fill` to get a continuous color scale. However, in this case you have to map `YEAR` also on the `group` aesthetic):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gganimate)

p <- gapminder::gapminder %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lifeExp, fill = factor(year))) + 
  geom_density(alpha=.2) + 
  xlab("Life Expectancy") + 
  ylab("Kernal density") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Year"))

p + 
  transition_time(year) + 
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Edit:

As far as I can tell without having seen your dataset you have to adapt your code like so (from inspecting your code I guess that `YEAR` is a character. So you have to convert it to an integer):

```r
data_long <- data_decidious %>% 
  tidyr::gather("YEAR", "NDVI", colsPostNDVI) %>%    
  mutate(YEAR = str_remove(YEAR, 'meanNDVIyear')) %>% 
  mutate(YEAR = str_remove(YEAR, 'meanprefire_NDVI')) %>% 
  # Convert YEAR to integer
  mutate(YEAR = as.integer(YEAR)) 

p <- data_long %>%    
  ggplot(aes(NDVI,fill=factor(YEAR))) + 
  geom_density(alpha=.2) + 
  xlim(0.3, 0.7) + 
  ylim(0,46) +
  xlab("Mean NDVI") + 
  ylab("Kernal density") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Comparative"))

p + 
  transition_time(YEAR) + 
  ease_aes('linear')

anim_save("test.gif")
```

Comment: OOh thanks a lot stefan! By the way that graph you made is so nice. I change what you suggested and put `ggplot(aes(NDVI,group=YEAR))`. However the output R is giving me in the plots section is static. Maybe I have to save this somewhere to be able to seee it moving? I am trying `ggsave("TRY2.gif", width = 40, height = 24, units= "cm")`but it doesn't work. thanks again!

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo Thx. I just edited my code and added a revised version of your code. Hope that works. Not that easy without any data. (; BTW: `ggsave` will not work for the animation. It's for saving ggplots. Have a look at `gganimate::anim_save()`. The gganimate equvialent to ggsave.

Comment: Thanks again stefan! When runing `p +  transition_time(YEAR) + ease_aes('linear')`it gives the error `2: file_renderer failed to copy frames to the destination directory `

Comment: Hm. Did a fast google search. Could be a problem with permission rights. See https://community.rstudio.com/t/warning-message-file-renderer-failed-to-copy-frames-to-the-destination-directory/45261. Or a problem with the gifski package not installed. See https://community.rstudio.com/t/gganimate-file-renderer-failed-to-copy-frames-to-the-destination-directory/45507

Comment: Yes indeed! I find a dude with a lovely youtube tutorial! Go it working! Thanks a lot stefan and stay safe!